# A story where violence is outlawed

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember if I read it or watched it or I just dreamed it but is there a story where violence (fighting mostly) is forbidden/outlawed/physically unless you're doing it in a dedicated "arena". Underground arenas exist to resolve "shady" duels.

Comment: This is pretty broad as-is. Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome comes to mind immediately, but that's one possibility among many. If there's anything at all you can remember about this don't hesitate to add it to your question.

Comment: I've seen lots of SF stories which have "legalized dueling" as a way to settle personal disputes. For instance, there was one by Keith Laumer in which all the dueling was done with remote-controlled android bodies. A question: Do you remember if these duels were normally "to the death," or if they usually wrapped up before anyone had been killed?